# How to handle error when login with different domain in windows authentication?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

My asp.net application deployed in domain `aaa` with `Windows Authentication`. User tried login with domain `bbb`. It is not rejecting login prompt window. It is throwing error while access SQL server.

```
    Server Error in '/' Application.
    Login failed for user 'bbb\user'.
    Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

    Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 
'bbb\user'.

    Source Error:      

    Line 7:          username = username.Substring(pos + 1)
    Line 8:          
    Line 9:          Clients = (From c In SGAEntities.Dim_Client
    Line 10:                    Where c.App_Users_Clients.Any(Function(userclient) userclient.App_Users.Username = username And userclient.App_Users.RecordStatus = 1 And userclient.Access_Level = 1)
    Line 11:                     Select c).ToList()


    Source File: error   Line: 9

    Stack Trace:
```

### Web.config

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
<authorization>
  <deny users = "?" />
</authorization>
<identity impersonate="true"/>
```

How to stop user website access when he is trying to user different domain login?

### Update

As friend suggested, Changed Impersonate to `false`. Getting different error.

```
Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.
```

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.

Source Error:

Line 7:          username = username.Substring(pos + 1)
Line 8:
Line 9:          Clients = (From c In SGAEntities.Dim_Client
Line 10:                    Where c.App_Users_Clients.Any(Function(userclient) userclient.App_Users.Username = username And userclient.App_Users.RecordStatus = 1 And userclient.Access_Level = 1)
Line 11:                     Select c).ToList()

DB connection string is

```
    <add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Data.csdl|res://*/Data.ssdl|res://*
/Data.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='data
source=server;initial catalog=database;Trusted_Connection=Yes;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: Do you mean [like this](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/400d7190-1140-4b5a-8e15-5c435760eab4.mspx?mfr=true)?

Comment: Looks like your IIS application is connecting to the SQL server as the user - therefore, your user does not have permissions on the SQL server and on the database. Is your intent to have each user access the DB under their own identity, or do you want to A) create a SQL server account for that DB/app, or B) create a SQL server login for the IIS computer?

Comment: @ZaijiaN, looks like you did understand my question. Why website itself allowing to access the .net EF code. It suppose to stop user at login itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IIS, make sure anonymous access is not selected, only integrated windows authentication needs to be selected. Also I assume you mentioned authentication and authorization tags under `<system.web>` section.

Comment: I've seen your update,  I think you've anonymous enabled. Cross check it in IIS and make sure only Windows authentication is enabled because as you can see after impersonation is removed, it tries to use anonymous login. If it is not enabled, user gets blocked there by prompting with windows login box where user enters the credentials and then the request gets impersonated.

Answer (score 0):

When you're developing and running under IIS express, etc, Impersonate means it uses YOUR windows account for the SQL Server. When running under IIS directly, and Impersonate is off, it'll use the built-in Anonymous account. You should determine whether or not that's really how you want your SQL Server to be set up.

What i've done in the past is create a SQL Server login and specified that in the connection string; alternatively, you can configure SQL Server to give the IIS machine permissions.